# How can I pass a Type to a generic Class in java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, arraylist

everyone here! I want pass a Type to a generic Type, like Arraylist, how can I do this? I make a simple Example, so that you will know what I want, of course this code is wrong.

```
public static void passObjType(Object obj) {

    Class clazz = obj.getClass();

    ArrayList<clazz> arr = new ArrayList<clazz>();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();

    passObjType(hs);
}
```

I hope, if I input a HashSet object, the funktion PassObjType() will create a Arraylist with HashSet and If I input a String Object, then it will create a Arraylist with String. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do that. The type arguments has to be known at compile time. You can't add it at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java Generics to get the parameter of Object type, as below :

```
        public static<T> void passObjType(T e) {
             ArrayList<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
            String hp = new String();
            passObjType(hs);
            passObjType(hp);
        }
```

Comment: @NiksTyagi Nilks, thanks very much! this is what I want!!! ( I have now too low reputation (just 11), so I cannot vote... :( )

Comment: heheheh itsk ohk dear @user3279996 .Its good that ur issue is fixed

Comment: Oh, someone voted for my question, I get more reputation! I can finally vote now~~~~ :D

Comment: The parameter `e` is not used. It should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
public static <T> void passObjType(T obj) {
    ArrayList<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>();
    //...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    passObjType(hs);
}
```

But I am not sure if that is what you want since at runtime generic types are [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and `ArrayList<String>` is just `ArrayList` (which can store any Object).

Comment: The parameter `obj` is not used. It should be removed.

Comment: @newacct `obj` is not used directly but is needed to pass type used later as generic. Also we don't know how OP code will look like later so I decided to leave this parameter just in case it will be needed later.

Comment: "obj is not used directly but is needed to pass type used later as generic." Nope. It's not needed. The type parameter is determined by the caller.

Comment: OK, it is possible to explicitly set `T` type of method when it is called like `instance.<SomeType>passObjType()` and in this case `SomeType` will be used in place of `T` instead of getting it from `obj` (if it would be removed from method arguments) but this way OP would have to decide it while writing (so at compilation time), where it seems that point of the question was how to get this type at runtime: "*if I input a HashSet object, the funktion PassObjType() will create a Arraylist with HashSet and If I input a String Object, then it will create a Arraylist with String*".

Comment: It is ALWAYS decided at compilation time. Generics is only compile time.

Comment: OK, but that is not the point here. Point is to let compiler "figure out" type (and if it is OK to use it), based on passed object, not to make programmer code it every time. That is the whole point of generics.

Comment: Inference is very weak in Java. It can infer in some situations and not in others. In a compiler with better inference, you would not need to explicitly specify the type parameter, because all it needs to do is check that there exists a type parameter which would make it work. Just because inference is weak in a compiler does not justify passing in extra useless parameters.

Comment: Maybe somehow I am misunderstanding you. Can you provide code example of how you would solve this? Link to something like http://ideone.com/ would be OK but you could also (which is even better option) post separate answer so OP also could also read it.